# Вывод стикера на товар

Tags: php, битрикс

Код выводит стикер на товар, если у товара включенно соответствующее свойство. Мне нужно, что если включенно несколько свойств выводить все стикеры. Сейчас выводит стикер только первого включенного свойства.

```
[![if (array_key_exists("PROPERTIES", $arResult) && is_array($arResult\["PROPERTIES"\]))
{
    foreach (Array("STOCK" => "Акция", "SPECIALOFFER" => "", "SALE" => "SALE", "HIT" => "ХИТ", "TAMP"=>"Тампопечать","GRAV"=>"Гравировка","UF_PRINT"=>"УФ-Печать") as $propertyCode => $propertyCodeName)
        if (array_key_exists($propertyCode, $arResult\["PROPERTIES"\]) && intval($arResult\["PROPERTIES"\]\[$propertyCode\]\["PROPERTY_VALUE_ID"\]) > 0)
        {
                                    $sticker .= '<span class="xit" ';

                                    if($propertyCode == "STOCK") $sticker .= 'style="font-size:20px;"';
                                    if($propertyCode == "SPECIALOFFER") $sticker .= 'style="font-size:20px;background: url(/bitrix/templates/eshop_adapt_blue/img/travel-icons.png) 1px -1px no-repeat;"';
                                    if($propertyCode == "SALE") $sticker .= '<span class="xit" ';
                                    if($propertyCode == "TAMP") $sticker .= 'style="font-size:20px; top:320px; left:0px;background: url(/bitrix/templates/eshop_adapt_blue/img/tamp.png) 1px -1px no-repeat;"';
                                    if($propertyCode == "GRAV") $sticker .= 'style="font-size:20px; top:320px;left:10px;background: url(/bitrix/templates/eshop_adapt_blue/img/grav.png) 1px -1px no-repeat;"';
                                    if($propertyCode == "UF_PRINT") $sticker .= 'style="font-size:20px; top:320px; left:20px;background: url(/bitrix/templates/eshop_adapt_blue/img/uf_print.png) 1px -1px no-repeat;"';
                                    $sticker .= '>'.$propertyCodeName.'</span>';
            break;
        }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Они у вас там друг на друга не наложены в css при выводе страницы?

Comment: Нет, если убираю свойство "Хит", то выводится только первая иконка, где под Должен еще.

Comment: html бы код в вопрос добавили проблемного места со стикером.

Comment: Это компонент битрикс, и код с выводом в шаблоне компонента.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Цикл отрабатывает только один раз, убери `break;` из цикла.

Comment: Телепаты все-таки существуют ;)

Comment: Спасибо! Тупанул что-то!)